# How to filter Django ManyToManyField based upon exact queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How do we filter django model instances based upon the exact values in the `ManyToManyField`. Consider the following example:
Say, we have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    authors=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I want to filter all the books, which only have a given author of given ids. If I am looking to filter the queryset say by author ids `1, 2, 3`. I tried doing this:

```
Book.objects.filter(authors__id__in=[1,2,3])
```

This doesn't work, since it gives me the list of books that have authors with these ids along with other authors. How to filter books such that the authors are only in these ids

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `related_name` in **ManyToManyField** model field and then use it in the filter query.

```
Class Book(models.Model):
authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='authors')
```

and try to run the query:

```
Book.objects.filter(authors__id__in=[1,2,3])
```